# Calling super method from outside the child class

Tags: java

I have a class `Child` which extends the class `Parent`.

The class `Parent` is an abstract class.

In a class `ChildTest` I want to call the parent class constructor, something like this:

```
public void methodInChildTest(){
    Child c = new Child();
    c.super();
}
```

`c.super()` is the constructor for the abstract parent class.

Is this possible to do? if so, how can I do that ?

Comment: No you can't  do that. `super` refers to the parent of the current class only (`ChildTest` here). This also applies to parent methods e.g `super.foo()` .

Comment: You can only call the super method of a class from the constructor of a class that inherits from it, and only from the first line in that constructor (if you don't the default constructor of that base class is called anyway).

Comment: You already invoked the constructor for the parent class by creating the child.

Answer (score 4):

No. The `super` method can only be called as the first statement inside a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When it's not literally defined, when you are calling new Child() a Parent no argument constructor will be invoked as first excecution in the Child consructor.
There is no other way to call the subclass constructor than from the Child constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, `super()` with parameters or without it can be called only as the first command in class constructor.

Those JLS points may help for better understanding:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7 (which defines that constructor may *only start* with `ExplicitConstructorInvocationopt`.

```
    ConstructorBody:
        { ExplicitConstructorInvocationopt BlockStatementsopt }
```

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1 (construction of `ExplicitConstructorInvocation` including `super()` call):

```
    ExplicitConstructorInvocation:
        NonWildTypeArgumentsopt this ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
        NonWildTypeArgumentsopt super ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
        Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt super ( ArgumentListopt ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, you cannot. `super` is only applicable in a constructor extending the parent class. You may want to take a look into Oracle explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0):

> `super ()` can only be called within the constructor method in the class.

```
public class Child extends SomeClass{
    public Child(){
       super();
    }
}
```